# Calculating Kestrel Inbound / Outbound traffic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm looking for a way to calculate amount of traffic that goes through ASP.NET Core Kestrel?

My initial thought is to have a middleware that handles all requests and sum them up, and i was wondering if there is any better approach for this?

Since it requires a new custom implementation for StaticFiles middleware (to include static files too).

(this features is already in IIS)

Answer (score 0):

Get metrics with [prometheus-net](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net) and visualize metrics(active requests, total requests, response time, throughput etc) with [grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana).